# No key value; pare [keyvaluepair]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, burninate-request, synonym-request

[keyvaluepair](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/keyvaluepair) may be a synonym of [key-value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/key-value).

Or maybe burninate [keyvaluepair](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/keyvaluepair) and retag since the other tag is more used and better documented.

I do not have enough meta experience to understand which course of action is correct here, nor do I have enough rep to make a synonym.

---

[keyvaluepair](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/keyvaluepair) 155 questions, 0 followers, viewed 20 times, active 2 years ago

[key-value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/key-value) 1205 questions, 20 followers, viewed 45 times, active 3 years ago

Comment: 1) Some tag stats would be really helpful. (number of questions tagged, followers, etc) 2) When in doubt, [use both tags?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33200023/map-key-value-pair-based-on-similarity-of-their-value-in-spark) 3) `KeyValuePair` is a type in the .net framework at least, eliminating the .net [questions for that tag](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/keyvaluepair+-c%23+-vb.net+-.net) reduces the count to 77 from 155. 4) It's too late at night for me to remember what the general consensus is about whether framework classes are supposed to be completely burned.

Comment: keyvaluepair is incoherent, it should not be a tag.

Comment: "No key value; pare [keyvaluepair]"?

Comment: *"[pare](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/pare#Verb)"* - *"2. (transitive, often with down or back) To reduce, diminish or trim gradually something as if by cutting off."*